# After time machine restore, zillions of .com.apple.backupd.mdmv files?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I used time machine to restore OSX. After restoring, there are zillions of `.com.apple.backupd.mdmvXXXXXX` files everywhere. `XXXXXX` is a seemingly random number, typically 7-8 digits long.

There seems to be at least one of these in each directory. Sometimes many.

The files are owned by root, and permissions 600. When I sudo cat them, I get XML similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>DateStarted</key>
    <date>2014-12-29T11:59:01Z</date>
    <key>FileID</key>
    <integer>12059719</integer>
    <key>NameSpaceID</key>
    <integer>2422653229</integer>
    <key>NewPath</key>
    <string>Users/username/SomeFileName</string>
    <key>SourcePath</key>
    <string>Users/username/Somepath1/Somepath2/SomeFileName</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I make the observation that the `FileID` matches the `XXXXXX` in the file name `.com.apple.backupd.mdmvXXXXXX`.

So what are these `.com.apple.backupd.mdmv` files? Should I do a recursive find and `rm` all these files on my hard disk? They aren't causing any harm in particular - but they replicate all over the place in dropbox and file sync and backup programs that I use.